# Modelica: identify instability / cyclic pattern and issue warning

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am trying to create a generalized warning block to identify equipment cycling. The purpose is that user can drag and drop this Modelica block and connect it to a sensor or equipment and the block will look for a cyclic pattern and issue a warning in the simulation log.

I have created a block that issues a warning everytime the variable crosses the range using `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print` and zero crossing logic (to limit the warning once per limit cross and avoid repetition of the wrning till the time variable stays out of the given range).

To identify a cyclic pattern, I was thinking of `der(u)` with a counter to calculate number of maxima and minima in the given period. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe use `assert(condition, message);` instead? http://book.xogeny.com/components/components/component_models/#assertions

Comment: For this generalized block, I need the simulation to continue even if the equipment is cycling. `assert` command stops the simulation when the condition is violated. However, I was not aware of the `AssertionLevel.warning` mentioned in the link. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option where to sample the signal, but this may be a problem when -- in a stability analysis -- you may not know what a critical frequency and thus a critical sampling frequency is.

I think there is unfortunately no best case to do it. There was a discussion going on this issue in the [Modelica Association](https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/109) some time ago. So, for continuous signals determining the zero crossings of the derivative of the signal is a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I am taking similar approach, zero crossing of derivatives in a given time interval and comparing the local minima and maxima with previous ones.